# I'm having problems binary reading a .csv to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, ftp, ftplib

I'm reading a `.CSV` file from an FTP server, and would like to convert its content to a dictionary.

There is some problem when reading to `csv.DictReader`.

```python
from ftplib import FTP
from io import BytesIO
import csv
ftp = FTP('192.168.202.90')    
loggedOn = ftp.login(user='admin', passwd='admin')
loggedOn = loggedOn.endswith('OK') # '230 Login OK'  
if loggedOn:
    ftp.cwd('/CSV')
    Files = ftp.nlst()
    NewestFile = Files[-1] # last file in the list
    r = BytesIO()
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+NewestFile, r.write)
    data = r.getvalue().decode("utf-8")
    print(r.getvalue())
    print(data)
    for row in csv.DictReader(data, delimiter=','):
        print(row)
    ftp.close()
```

`OUTPUT OF 'print(r.getvalue())':`

```
b'CheckBox_T100,TestedDatetime\nYes,2020-05-24'
```

`OUTPUT OF 'print(data):`

```
CheckBox_T100,TestedDatetime
Yes,2020-05-24
```

`OUTPUT OF for loop 'print()':`

```
{'C': 'h'}
{'C': 'e'}
{'C': 'c'}
{'C': 'k'}
{'C': 'B'}
{'C': 'o'}
{'C': 'x'}
{'C': '_'}
{'C': 'T'}
{'C': '1'}
{'C': '0'}
{'C': '0'}
{'C': '', None: ['']}
{'C': 'T'}
{'C': 'e'}
{'C': 's'}
{'C': 't'}
{'C': 'e'}
{'C': 'd'}
{'C': 'D'}
{'C': 'a'}
{'C': 't'}
{'C': 'e'}
{'C': 't'}
{'C': 'i'}
{'C': 'm'}
{'C': 'e'}
{'C': 'Y'}
{'C': 'e'}
{'C': 's'}
{'C': '', None: ['']}
{'C': '2'}
{'C': '0'}
{'C': '2'}
{'C': '0'}
{'C': '-'}
{'C': '0'}
{'C': '5'}
{'C': '-'}
{'C': '2'}
{'C': '4'}
```

how do I get a proper directory

```
{'CheckBox_T100': 'Yes', 'TestedDatetime': '2020-05-24'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution myself. I had to include `StringIO` as well.

```python
from ftplib import FTP
from io import BytesIO
from io import StringIO
import csv
ftp = FTP('192.168.202.90')    
loggedOn = ftp.login(user='admin', passwd='admin')
loggedOn = loggedOn.endswith('OK') # '230 Login OK'  
if loggedOn:
    ftp.cwd('/CSV')
    Files = ftp.nlst()
    NewestFile = Files[-1] # last file in the list
    r = BytesIO()
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+NewestFile, r.write)
    data = r.getvalue().decode("utf-8")
    for row in csv.DictReader(StringIO(data)):
        print(row)
    ftp.close()
```